# Google-Voice-java getSMS()

Tags: java, sms, google-voice

I am trying to use the google-voice-java API to read texts from a google voice account. I cannot find much documentation on using it other then the code.google.com page. I just need a little help on how to correctly use getSMS();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google-voice-java API will simply return back raw HTML of your Google Voice data. Thus, you need to parse through the HTML returned by `getSMS();`, and do with the data as you see fit.

If you'd like to just see what the data returned looks like at a console window, do the following

```
Voice voice = new Voice(userName, password);
String sms = voice.getSMS();
System.out.println(sms);
```

Based on that, you can see what the HTML looks like and how to parse through it.

Edit: Probably worth noting that you need to include the [additional dependency jars](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/downloads/list) to your build path; that should be more explicitly clear on their [GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/wiki/GettingStarted)!

Edit 2: Based on your comment below, there are the `getUnreadSMS()` and `markAsRead(msgID)`, but the former appears to return read SMS messages along with the unread ones.

If you notice at the top of the response XML returned by the `getSMS()` method (and majority of the other API methods), there is JSON data in the `<json>` element, which seems to have all the necessary information you need (including a `isRead` variable to indicate if a SMS is marked read, or not).

Pull down a response from the `getSMS()` method and use this [online JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to better inspect the data in the `<json>` element, so you have an idea of what's in there. When you paste in the JSON data into the online viewer, omit the leading `<![CDATA` and trailing `]>` inside the `<json>` element.

I would just setup a JSON parser (maybe even use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) and create SMS model objects based on the JSON data, ignoring the HTML completely; for unread messages, you want JSON objects with the `isRead` field set to `false`, obviously. You could then use the `id` field to pass into the `markAsRead(msgID)` method, to mark them read (I just tested this method and it works).

Comment: Yeah I am already using this. I am trying to figure out a few other things like only new messages and flagging a message as read after received.

Comment: Thank you though for responding

Comment: awesome this will help a lot I think